# Simple Regular Expression to return text from Wordpress title - qtranslate plugin

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, qtranslate

I am using qtranslate wordpress plugin to store blog content in multiple languages. Now I need to extract content from qtranslate tags.

```
$post_title  = "<!--:en-->English text<!--:--><!--:it-->Italian text<!--:-->";
```

What would be the php code & regular expression to return text and language from this string?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php
$post_title  = "<!--:en-->English text<!--:--><!--:it-->Italian text<!--:-->";

$regexp = '/<\!--:(\w+?)-->([^<]+?)<\!--:-->/i';
if(preg_match_all($regexp, $post_title, $matches))
{
    $titles = array();
    $count = count($matches[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $titles[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
    }
    print_r($titles);
}
else
{
    echo "No matches";
}
?>
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [en] => English text
    [it] => Italian text
)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Works like a charm :) Great job Atli! 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These are all brilliant examples. However, I recently discovered qTranslate has their own function available:

```
qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage($post_title);
```

Which will grab the current language and fail over to the default.