# How to split a language string (Wordpress qTranslate) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, qtranslate

I've got this javascript string:

```
"<!--:fr-->Photos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:-->"
```

And I need to parse it to get every "language" in distinct strings. The ideal would be to have a function like:

```
function getText(text, lang){
    // get and return the string of the language "lang" inside the multilang string "text"
}
```

That I can call like that:

```
var frenchText = getText("<!--:fr-->Photos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:-->","fr");
// and would return:
// frenchText = Photos
```

If anyone know a good way to do that, probably with a regexp that would be FANTASTIC!!!

Comment: This question is answered using PHP here, if anyone is interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853406/simple-regular-expression-to-return-text-from-wordpress-title-qtranslate-plugi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think much explanation is necessary; you just add `lang` to a template for your regex and get the first backref (the `(.*?)` part). I don't believe any part of your supplied string constitutes a [reserved character](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/regexp_special_characters.html). Note that you could include some error handling in case no match is found, but I'll leave that to the OP:

```
function getText(text, lang) {
  // Builds regex based on supplied language
  var re = new RegExp("<!--:" + lang + "-->(.*?)<!--:-->");

  // Returns first backreference
  return text.match(re)[1];
}
getText("<!--:fr-->Photos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:-->", "fr");
// returns "Photos"
```

Comment: how to check in a string like:

"[:fr]Photos[:en]Pictures" ?
thank you!

Comment: yes @brymck how to check it with "[:fr]french[:en]english[:]" ?? thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Better to have the language set by PHP:

```
var lang = '<?php echo qtrans_getLanguage(); ?>';
function getText(text) {
  // Builds regex based on supplied language
  var re = new RegExp("<!--:" + lang + "-->(.*?)<!--:-->");

  // Returns first backreference
  return text.match(re)[1];
}
getText("<!--:fr-->Photos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:-->");
```

Answer (score 0):

As commenters from top the top asked: for strings like [:fr]french[:en]english[:] you can use the following:

```
function getText(mtext, lang) {
     // Builds regex based on supplied language
    var re = new RegExp("\\[:" + lang + "\\](.*?)\\[:","s");                          
    
    // Returns first backreference
    return mtext.match(re)[1];
}
```